# How to find two column Data If if find then third column to find the data

Tags: excel, vba

Please find the image you will we find all the information sorry for not able to explain in my word but i explain in picture please help me please request you

[image]

Comment: Dude, you need to explain your question here, if you are not able to explain your question at least, we can't help you propertly, take your time... .

Comment: Use Google Translation! Describe your issue in your language and let it do the English translation! We won't give you code just with a image...

Comment: First I Need To Paste A Column Data in B Column When I Receive Data in B Column Then i again check data with D Column Data When Data Match it need to print in G Column With Suppler Name I hope you can understand this example also i attach picture please check

Comment: Ok Again i try to explain you in my word I have some data in column A i need to paste these data in column b without blank when i receive data in b column i need to compare b column data to Column D Data when It Match then print the name in g column with suppler name again loop will go on D Column and search next data if found then print with supplier name I hope you able to understand Please help please

Comment: I am not able to find VB code of this please help me above picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tried to follow your picture, I had the same issue and for that i use this function.

So you should put both codes in the same module. I also respect columns as you showed in the picture.

I hope it will help you.

***EDIT:***

```
 Sub test()
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Lastrow2 As Long, Lastrow3 As Long


    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

        .Range("B2:B" & Lastrow).Value = .Range("A2:A" & Lastrow).Value

        For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & Lastrow)
            If cell.Value = "" Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = cell
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With

Lastrow2 = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow3 = Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Lastrow2

Range("G" & i) = Range("B" & i) & " " & LookUpConcat(Range("B" & i), Range("D1:" & "D" & Lastrow3), Range("E1:" & "E" & Lastrow3), ",")

Next i

   End Sub
```

Here the function:

```
Function LookUpConcat(ByVal SearchString As String, SearchRange As Range, ReturnRange As Range, _
                      Optional Delimiter As String = " ", Optional MatchWhole As Boolean = True, _
                      Optional UniqueOnly As Boolean = False, Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False)

  Dim X As Long, CellVal As String, ReturnVal As String, Result As String

  If (SearchRange.Rows.count > 1 And SearchRange.Columns.count > 1) Or _
     (ReturnRange.Rows.count > 1 And ReturnRange.Columns.count > 1) Then
    LookUpConcat = CVErr(xlErrRef)
  Else
    If Not MatchCase Then SearchString = UCase(SearchString)
    For X = 1 To SearchRange.count
      If IsError(SearchRange(X)) Then GoTo Continue
      If MatchCase Then
        CellVal = SearchRange(X).Value
      Else
        CellVal = UCase(SearchRange(X).Value)
      End If
      ReturnVal = ReturnRange(X).Value
      If MatchWhole And CellVal = SearchString Then
        If UniqueOnly And InStr(Result & Delimiter, Delimiter & ReturnVal & Delimiter) > 0 Then GoTo Continue
        Result = Result & Delimiter & ReturnVal
      ElseIf Not MatchWhole And CellVal Like "*" & SearchString & "*" Then
        If UniqueOnly And InStr(Result & Delimiter, Delimiter & ReturnVal & Delimiter) > 0 Then GoTo Continue
        Result = Result & Delimiter & ReturnVal
      End If
Continue:
    Next

    LookUpConcat = Mid(Result, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: No This code copy a column data into b and display the  data in g column thanks manu

Comment: I edit the code, now the code copy from columnA to B without space. Then from B to G as you said above. Tell me if its ok